# confusion about basic AJAX code

Tags: php, javascript, xml, ajax, wamp

```
<script>
    try {
        function xmldo() {
            var xmlhttp;
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("para").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                }
            }
            var URL = "http:\\127.0.0.1\ajax.php";
            xmlhttp.open("GET", URL, true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    } catch (err) {
        document.write(err.message);
    }
</script>
<p id="para">Hey message will change</p>
<br>
<button type="button" onclick="xmldo()">Click me</button>
```

This is my code webpage I want to change the content of #para.innerHTML by the respnse in my another php file ajax.php

```
<?php
$response="hey is text changed";
echo $response;
?>
```

I am using wamp so i placed my ajax.php in my www folder and set the location of file on server as 127.0.0.1/ajax.php [URL] but i on pressing the button the text at para placeholder is not getting changed.
I am new to AJAX so must be missing on some points. Plz help me with them.

Comment: I would suggest you use a library such as jQuery to do AJAX requests - it's main benefit is that it takes less code and works across a variety of browsers.

Comment: Did you try to change `"http:\\127.0.0.1\ajax.php"` to `"http://127.0.0.1/ajax.php"`?

Comment: @ajtrichards I have no idea about Jquery right now but thanks a lot for your valuable suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

Change the slashes in your URL.

You have: `http:\\127.0.0.1\ajax.php` but the correct way is: `http://127.0.0.1/ajax.php`

I would also suggest using jQuery to perform AJAX requests - it's much simpler and you write less code!

I've added an example below written in jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("#button_id").click(function(){

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1/ajax.php',
            cache: false,
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'HTML',
            error: function (e){
                console.log(e);
            },
            success: function (response){
                $("#para").empty().append(response);
            }
        });

    });

});
</script>

<p id="para">Hey message will change</p><br>
<button type="button" id="button_id">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Apparently success: is deprecated in the latest jQuery (I only actually found out about this the other day !) its done: now

Comment: Plz sove my problem and provide me correct code for javascript as presently I only know it.And that url slashes dont make an impact in result but changed them

Comment: @Dave The `success` **option** is **not** deprecated. The `.success()` **method**/**callback** is. You could use `$.ajax({}).success(function () {});` but now you use `$.ajax({}).done(function () {})`

Comment: Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks are deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.

Comment: @Dave So how did you get that the `success:` **option** is deprecated from that?

Comment: @ajtrichards No error messages Sir thats why i am all puzzled up here

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: @Dave I don't know/care who told you that, but they were most likely referring to the **callback**, which is totally different from the **option**. The object returned from an `$.ajax()` call is a `jqXHR`. It had/has methods like `.success()`. Those are deprecated. But the options that pass into `$.ajax()` like "success" are not deprecated.

Comment: @Ian you are correct as I said I didn't actually bother reading up on it until questioned now.  I use quite an old jquery so don't keep massively up on the latest changes.

Comment: @Dave No problem. I just want to make sure we know which is actually deprecated :)

Comment: @Everyone Plz solve my problem quickly as i m stuck and cannot continue my learning.

Comment: Why don't you just use the jquery example? It does exactly what you want.